# Spacing issue between two divs in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am beginner in wordpress development, I am making a website for a company there is one issue is that when I add footer then creating space between above div and footer div [This is webpage link where issue is that](http://noeticworld.com/contact-us/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check my image below.

http://prntscr.com/m2i33y

You have to remove padding on this css property.

```
.page-wrap, .content-wrapper, .content-area .hentry:first-child{
  padding-bottom:0px !important;
}
.entry-footer{
  margin-top:0px !important;
 }
```

Comment: still have a space in between

Comment: Do you want to remove all space?

Comment: see the webpage link

Comment: You have to add my css to your css file and check with hard refresh.

Comment: You can add your css to this css file
http://noeticworld.com/wp-content/themes/sydney/style.css